# angular-route not working after minification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I am using gulp to minifiy  angular js files the following are minfied with `gulp` and the final file is outputed in `libs.js`

```
var files = [
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    'node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js'
]
```

the problem is angular routing not working after minfication

```
route.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/test', {
        templateUrl:'app/test.html',
        activetab:'emp',
        controller:'WelcomeController'
    }).
    when('/next',{
        templateUrl:'app/next.html',
        activetab:'emp',
        controller:'WelcomeController'
    })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/next'})
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="main" >
    <a href="#test">test</a>
         <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
```

However when i include the CDN links instead of minfied file everything works fine

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js" ></script>
```

**UPDATE**

Gulp task for minfication

```
var files = [
    'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    'node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js'
]

    gulp.task('libs', function () {
        return gulp.src(files)
            .pipe(concat('libs.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('resources/assets/build'))
            .pipe(ngAnnotate())
            .pipe(uglify({
                mangle:false
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js'));

    });
```

**UPDATE**

when click on the link corresponding controller works but the view is not loaded

Comment: Do you receive any error in console?

Comment: No errors that makes me creepy

Comment: Can you post your gulp task configuration?

Comment: @31piy anything wrong with my gulp configuration??

Comment: did u check the template location after building..

Comment: where can i check ??

Comment: @Nirus there is no change in template locations

Comment: Are you loading the `libs.js` file using a script tag ?

Comment: yes its loaded with script tag